# Facebook permissions

Tags: facebook

Suppose I have a website that wants to access a Facebook's user account information. Usually, the user is presented with all the permissions the website is asking for, and can either allow or deny them as a whole.

Is it possible to let the user choose (with checkboxes on each permission on the authorization screen, for example) which permissions he wants to give the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be possible but it would need to be done in two stages.

1. Firstly you would have to present the user with your own dialog where they can choose their prefered permissions.
2. Secondly you would have to authorise the user with the selected permissions via a Facebook dialog.

If you're looking for an example the Facebook Graph Explorer already does this:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

The bigger issue would be keeping track of the users available permissions and reacting according.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunatly not out of the box. (but this could be changed sometime in the future, as FB displays a required next to the rights if you look on the rights you give to an app)

I used to ask the required prems, and let the user add optional perms via a click, which again opens the perm dialog but only with the perms the user not already give to the site.

for an example. user sign in form, beside the "Hometown" field i have a button "Fill from facebook" if user hasn'T given me that right to access user_hometown i call for the right and fill the form.

see this post for a good explanation on the why and how:
http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/jssdk/learning_jssdk_12.php